# assigning textvariable to entry causes validation to be disabled on DoubleVar

Tags: python-3.x, validation, exception, tkinter

I am modifying tk.Entry() to validate a numeric input and notify a user if there was an error in applying it.

Beginning with the code below:

```
import tkinter as tk

class FloatEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Entry.__init__(self, parent, validate="focusout", validatecommand=self.validate, *args, **kwargs)

    def validate(self):
        try:
            print(float(self.get()))
            return True
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
            return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.bind_all("<1>", lambda event:event.widget.focus_set()) # make all widgets focusable
    var = tk.DoubleVar()
    frame = tk.Frame()
    frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    FloatEntry(frame, textvariable=var).pack()
    tk.Label(frame, textvariable=var).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

This results in the exception being triggered and printing, "could not convert string to float:". After this, neither the try nor the except in validate() are triggered again, so I assume it somehow returned None and disabled validation (I could be wrong here).

If I change the variable `var = DoubleVar()` to `var =tk.StringVar()`, then the validation works as expected, printing the float if the string can be parsed as a float, and printing the exception otherwise.

Finally, if I add a check to the value returned by get() before the try/except block, validation works as expected as well.

```
def validate(self):
        try:
        val = self.get()
            if(val is not ''):
            print(float(self.get()))
            return True
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
            return False
```

What is causing validation to be disabled on creation of a FloatEntry object?(or if that isn't happening, what is?)

Comment: Which behavior do you mean in the sentence "what is causing this behavior"? Are you asking what is causing validation to be turned off?

Comment: Yes, sorry I guess that wasn't clear. Validation gets turned off when a ValueError is thrown when the FloatEntry is initialized and I don't understand why. I'm not really even positive that's what was happening.

I'll extend the question and add my output to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be honest and say I don't fully understand why this is happening. However, a simple workaround seems to be to configure the `validatecommand` after you've called the `__init__` of the superclass:

```
class FloatEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Entry.__init__(self, parent, validate="focusout", *args, **kwargs)
        self.configure(validatecommand=self.validate)
```

When I make the above changes, I see the `validate` being called every time the widget loses focus.

Comment: Right, but a ValueError is caught and handled by validate(). And that function *is* called once, when the class is initialized, just not again. Further evidenced by the program working if I first check for an empty string before the try/except block, and after initialization, if float(self.get()) throws another value error, it's caught and handled properly (returning False)